# fatal: ambiguous argument 'release/1.0.0.0...1.0.0.17': unknown revision or path not in the working tree

Tags: git, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

Im trying to modify a jenkins shared library method to show the commits between tag and the current branch.

steps.sh(script: 'git log branchname...tagname --oneline')

I use the command  git log branchname...tagname --oneline, i always receive this below error in jenkins whereas  my local is working fine with the same command

fatal: ambiguous argument 'release/1.0.0.0...1.0.0.17': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.

Is it something to do with Jenkins , im really stuck with this can anyone please help me

Comment: What happenes if you run `git rev-parse release/1.0.0.0 1.0.0.17`?

Comment: Are the names perhaps `release/1.0.0.0` and `release/1.0.0.17`? If so you need to mention the `release/` part in both sections. Did you really want the three-dot symmetric-difference syntax?

Comment: This happens only when i execute it with groovy